# JQuery getting and setting height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, height

I am trying to have the same height for the div '.impress' as for the div '.page' but the height is not displayed correctly for my '.impress' div (the '.impress' is to small).

JQuery:

```
var getHeight = $('.page').height();
$(".impress").css('height', getHeight+200);
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: When using the `css` function you are setting the raw style. `height` needs units like `px`: `.css('height', getHeight+200+'px')`.

Comment: Thank, you I added all this but when I refresh my page it still shows the old preview (I tested it but it stays the same all the time)

Comment: Finished [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9rMb/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use jquery's height() method to set the height:

```
$(".impress").height(getHeight+200)
```

Or, if you are using `css('height',...)` be sure to include units, in your case:

```
$(".impress").css('height', (getHeight+200) + 'px')
```

Comment: he _is_ using jQuery to set the height of `.impress`

Comment: Thank, you I added all this but when I refresh my page it still shows the old preview (I tested it but it stays the same all the time)

Comment: @JSHelp, can you add `console.log('getHeight=' + getHeight);` line in the code before setting the height and then run the page and check the log output?

Comment: Works all fine now. Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that the DOM is loaded and ready before accessing the Height of `.impress`?

Make sure this is taking place in `$(document).ready(function() {});` to ensure `.impress` has been laid out and has a height.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but i have that

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the `.page` exists.

```
if($('.page').length){
    var getHeight = parseInt($('.page').height());
    $(".impress").css('height', getHeight+200);
}
else{
    alert('oops');
}
```

### Update:

and if `$('.page')` exists then make sure it has some height. A parent with all children floated *might* have `height = 0`